# Accuracy improves through Epochs but returns to initial accuracy for Evaluation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, data-processing

I am working on a project to recreate the results of a study using Neural Networks on EEG datasets. Throughout my time working on the project, I have been having repeated issues where the model has some accuracy improvements throughout the epochs, but for the evaluation, the accuracy always returns to the initial amount, specifically 1/NUM_CLASSES. Where NUM_CLASSES is the number of classification categories. I am honestly stuck at this point, I believe the model is overfitting and have attempted to adjust my data preprocessing to compensate, but have had little luck.

The code is as follows:

```
# Filters out warnings
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# Imports, as of 3/10, all are necessary
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import layers
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras.layers import Conv3D, Input, Dense, Activation, BatchNormalization, Flatten, Add, Softmax
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

from DonghyunMBCNN import MultiBranchCNN

# Global Variables

# The directory of the process data, must have been converted and cropped, reference dataProcessing.py and crop.py
DATA_DIR = "../datasets/BCICIV_2a_cropped/"
# Which trial subject will be trained
SUBJECT = 1

# The number of classification categories, for motor imagery, there are 4
NUM_CLASSES = 4
# The number of timesteps in each input array
TIMESTEPS = 240
# The X-Dimension of the dataset
XDIM = 7
# The Y-Dimension of the dataset
YDIM = 6
# The delta loss requirement for lower training rate
LOSS_THRESHOLD = 0.01
# Initial learning rate for ADAM optimizer
INIT_LR = 0.01
# Define Which NLL (Negative Log Likelihood) Loss function to use, either "NLL1", "NLL2", or "SCCE"
LOSS_FUNCTION = 'NLL2'
# Defines which optimizer is in use, either "ADAM" or "SGD"
OPTIMIZER = 'SGD'
# Whether training output should be given
VERBOSE = 1
# Determines whether K-Fold Cross Validation is used
USE_KFOLD = False
# Number of ksplit validation, must be atleast 2
KFOLD_NUM = 2
# Specifies which model structure will be used, '1' corresponds to the Create_Model function and '2' corresponds to Donghyun's model.
USE_STRUCTURE = '2'

# Number of epochs to train for
EPOCHS = 10

# Receptive field sizes
SRF_SIZE = (2, 2, 1)
MRF_SIZE = (2, 2, 3)
LRF_SIZE = (2, 2, 5)

# Strides for each receptive field
SRF_STRIDES = (2, 2, 1)
MRF_STRIDES = (2, 2, 2)
LRF_STRIDES = (2, 2, 4)

# This is meant to handle the reduction of the learning rate, current is not accurate, I have been unable to access the loss information from each Epoch
# The expectation is that if the delta loss is < threshold, learning rate *= 0.1. Threshold has not been set yet.
class LearningRateReducerCb(Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        self.history = {}
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):

        for k, v in logs.items():
            self.history.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

        fin_index = len(self.history['loss']) - 1
        if (fin_index >= 1):
            if (self.history['loss'][fin_index-1] - self.history['loss'][fin_index] > LOSS_THRESHOLD):
                old_lr = self.model.optimizer.lr.read_value()
                new_lr = old_lr*0.1
                print("\nEpoch: {}. Reducing Learning Rate from {} to {}".format(epoch, old_lr, new_lr))
                self.model.optimizer.lr.assign(new_lr)

# The Negative Log Likelihood function
def Loss_FN1(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    return K.sum(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1) # This is another loss function that I tried, was less effective

# Second NLL function, generally seems to work better
def Loss_FN2(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    n_dims = int(int(y_pred.shape[1])/2)
    mu = y_pred[:, 0:n_dims]
    logsigma = y_pred[:, n_dims:]
    mse = -0.5*K.sum(K.square((y_true-mu)/K.exp(logsigma)), axis=1)
    sigma_trace = -K.sum(logsigma, axis=1)
    log2pi = -0.5*n_dims*np.log(2*np.pi)
    log_likelihood = mse+sigma_trace+log2pi
    return K.mean(-log_likelihood)


# Loads given data into two arrays, x and y, while also ensuring that all values are formatted as float32s
def load_data(data_dir, num):
    x = np.load(data_dir + "A0" + str(num) + "TD_cropped.npy").astype(np.float32)
    y = np.load(data_dir + "A0" + str(num) + "TK_cropped.npy").astype(np.float32)
    return x, y

def create_receptive_field(size, strides, model, name):
    modelRF = Conv3D(kernel_size = size, strides=strides, filters=32, padding='same', name=name+'1')(model)
    modelRF1 = BatchNormalization()(modelRF)
    modelRF2 = Activation('elu')(modelRF1)

    modelRF3 = Conv3D(kernel_size = size, strides=strides, filters=64, padding='same', name=name+'2')(modelRF2)
    modelRF4 = BatchNormalization()(modelRF3)
    modelRF5 = Activation('elu')(modelRF4)

    modelRF6 = Flatten()(modelRF5)

    modelRF7 = Dense(32)(modelRF6)
    modelRF8 = BatchNormalization()(modelRF7)
    modelRF9 = Activation('relu')(modelRF8)

    modelRF10 = Dense(32)(modelRF9)
    modelRF11 = BatchNormalization()(modelRF10)
    modelRF12 = Activation('relu')(modelRF11)
    return Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')(modelRF12)

def Create_Model():
    # Model Creation

    model1 = Input(shape=(1, XDIM, YDIM, TIMESTEPS))

    # 1st Convolution Layer
    model1a = Conv3D(kernel_size = (3, 3, 5), strides = (2, 2, 4), filters=16, name="Conv1")(model1)
    model1b = BatchNormalization()(model1a)
    model1c = Activation('elu')(model1b)

    # Small Receptive Field (SRF)

    modelSRF = create_receptive_field(SRF_SIZE, SRF_STRIDES, model1c, 'SRF')

    # Medium Receptive Field (MRF)

    modelMRF = create_receptive_field(MRF_SIZE, MRF_STRIDES, model1c, 'MRF')

    # Large Receptive Field (LRF)

    modelLRF = create_receptive_field(LRF_SIZE, LRF_STRIDES, model1c, 'LRF')

    # Add the layers - This sums each layer
    final = Add()([modelSRF, modelMRF, modelLRF])
    out = Softmax()(final)

    model = Model(inputs=model1, outputs=out)

    return model

if (LOSS_FUNCTION == 'NLL1'):
    loss_function = Loss_FN1
elif (LOSS_FUNCTION == 'NLL2'):
    loss_function = Loss_FN2
elif (LOSS_FUNCTION == 'SCCE'):
    loss_function = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'

# Optimizer is given as ADAM with an initial learning rate of 0.01
if (OPTIMIZER == 'ADAM'):
    opt = Adam(learning_rate = INIT_LR)
elif (OPTIMIZER == 'SGD'):
    opt = SGD(learning_rate = INIT_LR)

X, Y = load_data(DATA_DIR, SUBJECT)

if (USE_KFOLD):
    seed = 4
    kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=KFOLD_NUM, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
    cvscores = []

    for train, test in kfold.split(X, Y):
        if (USE_STRUCTURE == '1'):
            MRF_model = Create_Model()
        elif (USE_STRUCTURE == '2'):
            MRF_model = MultiBranchCNN(TIMESTEPS, YDIM, XDIM, NUM_CLASSES)
        # Compiling the model with the negative log likelihood loss function, ADAM optimizer
        MRF_model.compile(loss=loss_function, optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

        # Training for 30 epochs
        MRF_model.fit(X[train], Y[train], epochs=30, verbose=VERBOSE)

        # Evaluating the effectiveness of the model
        scores = MRF_model.evaluate(X[test], Y[test], verbose=VERBOSE)
        print("%s: %.2f%%" % (MRF_model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
        cvscores.append(scores[1]*100)

    print("%.2f%% (+/- %.2f%%)" % (np.mean(cvscores), np.std(cvscores)))

else:
    if (USE_STRUCTURE == '1'):
        MRF_model = Create_Model()
    elif (USE_STRUCTURE == '2'):
        MRF_model = MultiBranchCNN(TIMESTEPS, YDIM, XDIM, NUM_CLASSES)

    MRF_model.compile(loss=loss_function, optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

    MRF_model.fit(X, Y, epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=VERBOSE)

    _, acc = MRF_model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=VERBOSE)

    print("Accuracy: %.2f" % (acc*100))
```

The data is from the BCICIV 2A dataset, which consists of 25 channels. The 3 EOG channels are ignored, leaving 22 channels. These 22 channels are formatted into a 7x6 - 0 padded array to offer a more spatially relevant representation. We are using the sliding window method to compensate for a small dataset and then also are running a channel-wise average on each trial to
further process the data. The training results are as follows.

```
Epoch 1/10
666/666 [==============================] - 13s 17ms/step - loss: 4.0290 - accuracy: 0.3236
Epoch 2/10
666/666 [==============================] - 12s 18ms/step - loss: 3.9622 - accuracy: 0.3434
Epoch 3/10
666/666 [==============================] - 14s 21ms/step - loss: 3.9747 - accuracy: 0.3481
Epoch 4/10
666/666 [==============================] - 14s 21ms/step - loss: 3.9373 - accuracy: 0.3720
Epoch 5/10
666/666 [==============================] - 14s 21ms/step - loss: 3.9412 - accuracy: 0.3710
Epoch 6/10
666/666 [==============================] - 14s 21ms/step - loss: 3.9191 - accuracy: 0.3829
Epoch 7/10
666/666 [==============================] - 14s 21ms/step - loss: 3.9234 - accuracy: 0.3936
Epoch 8/10
666/666 [==============================] - 14s 21ms/step - loss: 3.8973 - accuracy: 0.3983
Epoch 9/10
666/666 [==============================] - 14s 21ms/step - loss: 3.8780 - accuracy: 0.4022
Epoch 10/10
666/666 [==============================] - 14s 21ms/step - loss: 3.8647 - accuracy: 0.3900
666/666 [==============================] - 5s 8ms/step - loss: 4.1935 - accuracy: 0.2500  
Accuracy: 25.00
```

Disregarding the poor accuracy, the fact that the accuracy falls to 25.00 after training is concerning. I half feel like I am missing something simple, but have been unable to resolve the issue.

Any advice or questions are welcome, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two potential reasons for the difference you are observing, but I don't have the time now to test them:

1. Both optimizers you are using, `SGD` and `Adam`, use a subset of the rows for training, not the entire dataset. This leads to the inconsistency you are observing.
2. BatchNorm works differently during train time and evaluation time.

Both cases point in the same direction: the evaluation of the accuracy and loss during training time is an aggregated estimate of per-batch results and in this scenario are being overly optimistic.

For testing 1, you can try setting a `batch_size` in the `fit` to `len(X)`. Note you might run out of memory and it will definitely be slow (it might be prohibitively slow).

For testing 2, you can try removing the BatchNorm steps.

Keep me posted if you work on these lines of thought!

Comment: Sorry for the late response on this, as of right now, I am not able to properly test the method you suggested first, attempting to use such a batch size exceeds my memory that is available. Sampling smaller batch_sizes results in little to no improvement.

For the second method, I removed all BatchNorms in the model and again had little to no improvement. 

For context, I am working to reproduce the paper from Zhao et. al, "A Multi-Branch 3D Convolutional Neural Network for EEG-Based Motor Imagery Classification", I have had immense difficulty finding results anywhere near they report.